# Is there a search engine for programmers that finds functions based on input/output values?

Tags: search-engine

Is there any program that helps to find a function from, say, Github based on what it should return?

Like I would like to make a checker if a string is a valid social security number in German. I have no idea how German social security numbers are formed but a database I need in my project gives some. Then I would ask/some codes that returns true if input is any German social security number that I can find in my database.

Comment: So, you would search for a function that gets a String as input and outputs a boolean? Good luck looking for the one where the String is a SSN. ;-)

Comment: Also, Wikipedia tells me there is no Social Security Number in Germany that is used by all social security systems. Make sure you know what exactly it is you want. There is Steuer-Identifikationsnummer, Rentenversicherungsnummer, and probably a bunch of other numbers that you could mean, but there seems to be no "Social Security Number". https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sozialversicherungsnummer